# Dwoo template search path

Tags: php, dwoo

can I somehow add paths where Dwoo is looking for templates from? I have two folders where I store my templates, and I would like to use **extends**-function across these two directories without having to do stuff like "../templates/template.tpl" or using absolute paths.

So, if I do this in my template

```
{extends "base.htm"}
```

I'd like Dwoo to look, for example, directories "/www/site/templates" and "/www/site/static" for this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the includePaths function of the Dwoo_Template_File class, for example:

```
$tpl = new Dwoo_Template_File('foo.html');
$tpl->setIncludePath(array('/www/site/templates', '/www/site/static'));
echo $dwoo->get($tpl, $data);
```

Then it should automatically look up relative paths from all those dirs and take the first that is found.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Couldn't figure to check Dwoo_Template_File API.